# JComboBox items from ResultSet Issues

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, resultset, implements

I am stuck here and see only one solution which I am trying to refrain from because, it will make my code look messy. I have a JComboBox.addPopupMenuListener in one class. I have another class which implements addPopupMenuListener. In the other class, I extract the items from DB and store them in a List.

I am completely clueless now on how do I add items from this List to JComboBox. Any ideas?

Problem - although I have declared JComboBox combobox; as public I am unable to use this combobox in the implementing class. What do I do? Below is the Code -

```
package tg.com.bugtracker.loginpage;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LoginPanel extends JPanel {

    public JComboBox<String> combobox;

    public LoginPanel() {
        GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
        setLayout(layout);
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        combobox = new JComboBox<>();
        combobox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 20));
        combobox.addPopupMenuListener(new loginNames());
        add(combobox, constraints);
    }
}
```

Implementing Class -

```
package tg.com.bugtracker.loginpage;

import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.List;

public class loginNames implements PopupMenuListener{

    @Override
    public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public List<String> loginNames;

    @Override
    public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent arg0) {
        String URL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\bharat.nanwani\\Desktop\\BugTrackerDB.accdb";
        ResultSet rs;
        PreparedStatement p;
        String sqlquery = "SELECT FirstName FROM UserDetails;";
        try {
            Connection cnn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
            p = cnn.prepareStatement(sqlquery);
            rs = p.executeQuery();
            rs.close();
            p.close();
            while (rs.next()) {
                String names = rs.getString("FirstName");
                loginNames.add(names);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Read about the [ComboBoxModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html) that is the place to feed the JComboBox with data.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm just wondering why I can't use combobox (which I have declared as public) in my implementing class?

Comment: `loginNames` needs a reference to the JComboBox (or it's model) to be able to add items to the JComboBox

Comment: @Bharat Nanwani Swing follows MVC pattern. In this case: Model=ComboBoxModel, View=JComboBox, Controller=AnyKindOfListeners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `combobox` in class `loginNames` because `combobox` is a member of the `LoginPanel` class. I'm not sure if you've learned the details of classes and object though, so I will give you two possible fixes and then explain them.

Here are two fixes:

1) Change the declaration

`public JComboBox<String> combobox`

to

`public static JComboBox<String> combobox`.

Then use `LoginPanel.combobox` to access the combobox in the `loginNames` class.

2) Add the following constructor to `loginNames`:

```
private LoginPanel login;

public loginNames( LoginPanel login ) {
    this.login = login;
}
```

Then, you can access the combobox in `loginNames` class by typing `this.login.combobox`.

---

A basic concept of classes and objects is that you use classes as a template to create objects. `LoginPanel` is a class and you create `LoginPanel` objects with the code `new LoginPanel()`. Every object (i.e. instance of `LoginPanel`) will have some variables and methods associated with it. For example, in your not-working code, every `LoginPanel` object has a unique `JComboBox<String>` variable named `combobox` associated.

The reason why you cannot access `combobox` from `listNames` is that `listNames` does not know what `LoginPanel` object you are talking about. It knows there is a `LoginPanel` class, but there can exist 2 or more `LoginPanel` objects at any given time and those `LoginPanel` objects will all have different `combobox`es.

---

In the first fix provided, we added the `static` keyword to `combobox`. What `static` does is that it tells the computer that instead of having a different `combobox` for each `LoginPanel` object, we're just going to have one global `combobox` that all `LoginPanel` objects will share. More specifically, `combobox` becomes associated with the `LoginPanel` class and it is no longer associated with `LoginPanel` objects. If you do this, there can only be one `combobox` so you are able to refer to that in the `listNames` class with the code `LoginPanel.combobox`.

For the second fix, recall that we cannot just access `combobox` from the `listNames` class because there is a different `combobox` associated with every `LoginPanel` object (and more than 1 `LoginPanel` object may exist). In the second fix, we directly address this problem by passing a reference in the constructor to the specific `LoginPanel` object we're talking about. By passing this reference, we specify that `login` is the `LoginPanel` object we want to modify and it has a unique `combobox` that we're going to add our list elements to. Therefore, you are able to type `login.combobox` to access `combobox`.

---

Both fixes are not what would ideally be used. As others have mentioned, Java Swing follows the Model-View-Controller pattern, and so, it is expected that your applications using Java Swing will also use this pattern. The `ComboBoxModel` class would allow you to achieve this pattern. Adding a `static` keyword won't give you the Model-View-Controller pattern.

I looked at your code, and since you didn't fully following Java naming conventions, I figured you might be a bit new to Java and possibly object-oriented programming. Since you may not want to spend a lot of time learning how `ComboBoxModel` works and changing all your code to follow the Model-View-Controller pattern, I've offered what I hope is a quick alternative that is easier to explain conceptually and will get you the functionality you want.

Comment: 1+ Nice explanation :)

Comment: OMG! This explanation has made the entire concept clear in my head. Thank you so much!